What problems might arise from ignoring this race condition?
I wish to represent a service that receives triggers to run a particular task, however it only runs that task once at a given time while ignoring concurrent triggers.
My brain came up with an unconventional approach to this problem (it does that sometimes...).
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    once := &sync.Once{}
    var trigger = make(chan int)
    done := make(chan bool)
    onceBody := func(v int) func() {
        return func() {
            trigger <- v
        }
    }
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case v := <-trigger:
                fmt.Println("Triggered: ", v)
                once = &sync.Once{}
            case <-done:
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        i := i
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            once.Do(onceBody(i))
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    done <- true
}


I do understand that there are better solutions to this problem. I only wish to understand what problems might arise from this implementation.
I understand that a type of data race is happening with the once variable, however, I think it might not matter for this particular use-case.
Will the closure' stale pointer be problematic for the gc?
What problems might arise from this implementation?

This is not a problem for the gc. There is no guarantee which instance of once will be used. It is likely that none of the assignments to once will be visible to the goroutines because of the race.

There’s no reason to ever have a race. Correctness aside, even if there were a race which didn’t matter, it precludes you from using the race detector to detect other actual problems.

"What problems might arise from ignoring this race condition?" All of them.

There is no need to elaborate, race conditions produce unreliable runtime behaviour. So potentially all problems plus the ones you did not think about can happen.

One problem with race conditions is that if you violate the memory model, the effects will depend on the hardware you are running on.
While most modern CPUs guarantee atomicity for writes to properly aligned words (*sync.Once), there is no guarantee in the language, so your program could read a corrupted, partial written pointer on some exotic platform.
Even when running on modern CPUs the results of parallel writes and reads depend on the platform you are running on.
So what you really get and whether your program crashes due to a corrupted pointer depends on where you run this code.

See Implementation Restrictions for Programs Containing Data Races. If pointers are not larger than a machine word, a program will not read a corrupted, partial written pointer.

@CeriseLimón That's why I said “most modern CPUs guarantee” and “on some exotic platform”. I agree, partial reads a very unlikely.

To ignore triggers while doing the processing for a trigger, start a goroutine that receives and discard triggers in a loop.  Exit the loop when processing is done.
func ignore(trigger chan int, done chan struct{}) {
    for {
        select {
        case v := <-trigger:
            // Discard
        case <-done:
            return
        }
    }
}

func run(trigger chan int, done chan struct{}) {
    for {
        select {
        case v := <-trigger:
            d := make(chan struct{})
            go ignore(trigger, d)
            process(v)
            d <- struct{}{}
        case <-done:
            return
        }
    }
}

Run a demonstration on the playground.
